# Django weird symbols while downloading excel file (page also uses ajax)

Tags: python, django

Django returning weird symbols while trying to download excel file

[image: I can download excel but page which displays shows weird characters and symbols]

```
    file_name = 'data.xlsx'
    response = HttpResponse(open(file_name, 'rb'), content_type="application/xlsx")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=Report-{}.xlsx".format(datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

    return response
```

Comment: are you generating the file in django?

Comment: function just generates xlsx file with help of xlsx writer library, all I have to do is download file, I can download, but getting weird symbols and characters

Comment: can you try setting `content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"` in the httpresponse

Comment: it didn't work. Also page uses Ajax

Comment: xlsx is a binary format (compressed xml), you can't just open it in a web browser

Comment: I am not opening, I am downloading

Comment: It looks like a viable .xlsx file, at least it looks like a zipped file. Have you tried opening it directly, not downloading via Django? Can you unzip it? You need to establish that the original file is in fact good.